# How to get custom title view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using different layouts to show different styled titles in my application. The problem is that I can't get a reference to a specific Textview that exists in all of them. If I change the text, nothing happens.

Here is what I am doing:

```
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_bar);
```

The following method does not work:

```
public void setTitle(String text) {
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    if(txtTitle !=null) {
        txtTitleMoney.setText(text);
        Log.d("debug", "not null");
    } 
}
```

I get no error so I think I'm accessing the wrong view.

Hopefully someone can help me :)

Comment: why do you check on txtTitle for null and then modify the txtTitleMoney? how do you know that txtTitleMoney is not null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you set the same id ("`txtTitle`") to the `TextView` items in all of your different title layouts, then your code should work.
also make sure you call `setTitle()` after `setContentView()`.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
boolean customTitleSupported;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);     
    setContentView(R.layout.mainscreen);

    customTitleBar();
}

public void customTitleBar( ) {

    if (customTitleSupported) {
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                            R.layout.customtitlebar);
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById R.id.title);               
            title.setText(left);             
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am changing the layout on the fly. I don't call setFeatureInt only on creation but everytime my user changes the tab.

Comment: I am changing the layout on the fly ? means what it mean.